# algorithm for calculating a running clicks/second value (ala a speedometer)

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to figure out how to produce a running calculation of clicks per second (e.g. an app with a window I click on and it gives me a speedometer-like value of the 'speed' of my clicks in clicks per second).  For some reason the algorithm is eluding me.

It's easy to figure out if I just want to figure out clicks per second if at each second I report how many clicks happened in the last second.  But where it gets tricky is if there was one click in second 1, then 0 clicks in seconds 2-9 and 1 click in second 10.  Presumably that would be .2 clicks per second--although really only if it was kept up and averaged out to that over time.  If that click in second 10 was followed by 0 clicks for 40 seconds, then it should be 0 clicks/second, not .04 clicks/second.

So clearly I need some kind of window within which I'm willing to presume the clicks are part of a pattern, or at least associated with the last ones.  But it's just not making sense to me.

I'm using openframeworks for this, so have an update() function that is called more than once/second (say 30x/sec), and have a mousePressed() function that allows me to increment a variable to track the clicks.  i can use difftime() and time() to track whether I just crossed into a new second, and then use fmod() to figure out if I just crossed some larger interval.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: So what is your problem? And what you mean by "associated with the last ones"?

Comment: by 'associated' i mean: is the most recent click part of a pattern that includes a click from long ago, or was the clicks/hour speed at 0 and this most recent click is the start of a new speed?  my problem is fleshing out this algorithm and was hoping for some help.  pseudocode, c++, narrative ideas...any type that suggests how to go about this would be helpful.

Comment: Do you want a sliding 10 second window, or sequential 10 second windows? The latter is far simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to calculate the running average of the clicks per second. You would use a circular buffer of counters of a length of say 30 for a 30 second window. The average clicks per second is the sum of the counters divided by 30.
An index points to the current counter, the index is incremented modulo 30 every second, and the counter at the new position is set to zero.

example:

```
const unsigned BUFFER_SIZE = 30;
unsigned counters[BUFFER_SIZE];
unsigned current = 0;
time_t last;

void init() {
    time(&last);
}

void update() {
    time_t now;
    time(&now);
    while (now - last >= 1) {
        ++last;
        current = (current+1)%BUFFER_SIZE;
        counters[current] = 0;
    }
}

void mousePressed() {
    ++counters[current];
}

float average() {
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; ++i) {
        sum += counters[i];
    }
    return sum/BUFFER_SIZE;
}
```

Comment: The circular buffer is indeed the typical approach. I think there is an inconsistency though between the use of `difftime` and the `++last;` statement. The latter means you assume that regular operations are available on `time_t`, but in this case why not use `now - last` to compute the difference ?

Comment: You can maintain the average faster by keeping a total of the full contents of the circular buffer and subtracting the item you pop off the circular buffer, then adding the number you just added.

Comment: thanks for the help. i was headed in this direction but couldn't get there.  your implementation introduces an interesting side effect: a bit of lag.  with a buffer of 30 you avoid the problem of reading temporary lulls as stops, but also require 30 samples to register the actual speed in some cases. i.e. if I start clicking immediately at a rate of 1 click/sec., it takes nearly BUFFER_SIZE seconds to register it. i can lower BUF_SIZE to something like 5 and it minimizes the problem. it's as if there needs to be two trackers...one doing the running average and another watching for 'instant on'

Answer (score 0):

This is pseudo code, but I think it will do what you are asking:

```
onUpdate() {
   if (currentTime() - lastClickTime > idleTimeout) {
      // reset the clickometer to zero
   } else {
      // calculate the speed
   }
}

onMouseClick() {
   lastClickTime = currentTime();
   // and whatever else needs to happen
}
```

Basically you are just tracking the time of the last click, and making sure it happened within the idleTimeout, which you obviously have to define for some span of time.